# Shipping weight value is in decimal

Tags: magento-1.7, shipping, table-rates

I am using table rates.

In the menu `System > Configuration > Shipping Methods`, change the "Current Configuration Scope" to a website then an `Export` button will become available in the `Table Rates` section. The condition should be "`Weight vs. Destination`" to get the right file. Download the exported file and modify it to something like this;

```
Country  Region/State  Zip/Postal Code  Weight (and above)  Shipping Price
UK       *             *                0                   3.68
UK       *             *                1                   6.68
```

Now it is working fine, but if my product weight is `0.9` then it goes of `3.68` not for `6.68`. I want to calculate my price on decimal value of weight also.I am new here plz help me

Comment: can't you just add decimals in the weight column?